# No File or Directory Found when Deploying a Rails Application to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Rails application created from Windows (Win 7) to Heroku. Unfortunately, I am experiencing an error in Heroku saying that No such file or directory found when referring to Ruby.

I updated the first line of `bin/bundle`, `bin/rails` and `bin/rake` from `#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe` to `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` but it still did not work out. I then modified this line to `#!/usr/local/bin/ruby` but still got the same problem.

What are the steps involved to solve this issue please or Windows is a no-go for RoR?

The application is very simple and so far it does not use a database (not even sqlite3)